# Documentation for compiler gcc compiler flags?

Tags: linux, opengl, sdl

I am building a makefile for an SDL/OpenGL program.  In looking at the Makefile for the SDL2.0 examples, I see compiler flags such as DHAVE_OPENGL, and D_REENTRANT.  Nowhere in the man pages for gcc can I find information on either of these flags.  Where on the internet/my system can I find documentation about all the flags supported by gcc?

Answer (score 2):

the -D option is used not to define specific compiler flags but to [pass macro definitions to the preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html).

Indeed `-DHAVE_OPENGL` is like having `#define HAVE_OPENGL 1` in your source code. So they are not related to the compiler per se but just on the code you are compiling.

[Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC) you can find a comprehensive documentation of GCC options in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not compiler flags *per-se*. `-D` is a compiler flag, but what follows is a pre-processor definition. You will not find any information on what those mean in the compiler docs because it affects the behavior (e.g. which portions of the code are actually included during compilation) of the actual ***code*** that you are building.

So unfortunately, the only way you will know what defining those pre-processor tokens will do is if you investigate the source code you are compiling or if the library you are using documents them.

Generally speaking however, `HAVE_OPENGL` lets SDL know to compile GL-related code.

Re-entrancy is used for thread safety, and although `_REENTRANT` is not a standard pre-processor definition (though commonly used with some C stdlib implementations), it is safe to assume that it will cause your software to select re-entrant versions of functions whenever possible.